# Creating shadow for triangular div

Tags: html, css

How can we create shadow for triangular div? Here's a code which I was trying

Html

```
 <div id="triangle-down"></div>
```

CSS

```
 #triangle-down {
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 50px solid transparent;
     border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     border-top: 100px solid red;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
 }
```

This code creates the square shadow for the div tag. Now how can we create triangular shadow for this div tag ?

Comment: this will not work as .. left/ right are there (they acquired their space but not visible). so shadow is rectangular.
you can search for svg based solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Method 1](http://dabblet.com/gist/1592060)

### HTML

```html
<div class="triangle-with-shadow"></div>
```

### CSS

```css
.triangle-with-shadow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #999;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   top: 75px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:hover, .triangle-with-shadow:hover:after {
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

---

## [Method 2](http://jsfiddle.net/FrsGR/436/)

### HTML

```html
<span class="triangle">▼</span>
```

### CSS

```css
.triangle {
    color:red;
    font-size:100px;
    text-shadow: 0 0px 10px black;
}
```

Comment: This is basically a link only answer.  You really should pull something from that URL and use it in your answer.  Links become broken and if it does, your answer is worthless.

Comment: I went ahead and edited it for you to show you how you can make your answers more informational by including the code used from your link.

Comment: thanks :) I am new to stackoverflow :) I will learn as I go by :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option, most definitely better in ways, is using the `filter: drop-shadow();`.

This will mimic the shape to make a filter and I'm not kidding it mimics it to a tee. This will not only follow the object but it will also follow pseudo elements on the object.

Here is the `CSS`:

```
#triangle-down {
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 50px solid transparent;
     border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     border-top: 100px solid red;
     filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
     -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
     -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
     -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
     -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
}
```

Regular question [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/usRj4/).

---

With pseudo elements [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/usRj4/1/)

```
#triangle-down {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
     -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
     -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
     -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
     -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px black);
} 

#triangle-down:before {
    content: "";
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 15px solid transparent;
     border-right: 15px solid transparent;
     border-top: 30px solid red;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     left: 50%;
 }
```

---

[Filter information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

**Major consideration** is browser support, currently Webkit is the only supported browser.